# Javascript Error Class doesn't support Automation

Tags: javascript, pdf

I have links on a page that call a javascript function to open a window.

Some of the links are HTML and some are PDF.

The error occurs if I click one of the pdf links and then while that window is open i click any other link.

If I begin by clicking a html link and then any other link the error does not occur.

So clicking a pdf link first and then clicking another link will throw this error.

```
 w.location.href = url; <<< **********ERROR HERE *********************
```

html:

```
        helpMenu.add( new AnchorMenuItem("Features", "javascript:openHelpWindow('../html/help/features.html');") );
    helpMenu.add( new AnchorMenuItem("Overview", "javascript:openHelpWindow('../doc/Overview.pdf');") );
```

JS:

```
var w;

function openHelpWindow(url) 
{     
 w = window.open(url, "MSSTHelp", "resizable,scrollbars,height=700,width=900,screenX=100,screenY=100,left=100,top=100");    
 w.location.href = url; <<< **********ERROR HERE *********************
 w.focus();

}
```

Comment: Which browser? Have tested it here, no problems with opening either website or local files. However, the location.ref=url reference is unnessecary, it has already been set in window.open.

Comment: If i remove that line...I get the error "member not found" on `w.focus()`.....

Comment: I think JS gets confused when a pdf is set first